# download local copy of CentOS yum repository for offline use

Tags: centos, yum

I have a CentOS 5.6 machine set up on a private network without public internet access.  In the interest of time and frustration, I would prefer to be able to install packages using Yum as I would if the machine were online.  Is it possible to download a copy of the repositories that can be stored on a network local machine from which I can do this?  please provide me any instructions I might need if it is possible.

So to break it down, I want `yum install gcc` to install gcc without an internet connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple thing to achieve assuming you have a web server set up on your local machine.

If you need help with that, ask a new question :)

You basically rsync a repo to your local machine and set it up as a local website then point your URL at that in your yum configuration.

There is a pretty [straight forward guide on the steps involved on howtoforge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating_a_local_yum_repository_centos)

There will be a maintenance overhead moving forward with keeping your repo updated with updates to the main repositories, so I wouldn't recommend this as a good idea for everyone but if you have the need for a local repo ( for example, you have a lot of machines on a LAN and want to save on bandwidth ) then this can be a good way to go.

Comment: Is there an updated way to do this for centos 8?